Let's Encrypt ~/.acme.sh/acme.sh | string too long:crypto/asn1/a_mbstr.c:106:maxsize=64 error
I want to create a certificate with acme.sh script for my domain on centos 7.
MY domain is : "update.gerqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmgerqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm.site"
When i tried the command below i got error as mentioned below :
[root@artemis-art ~]# ~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d update.gerqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmgerqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm.site --standalone
[Sat Nov  2 14:30:34 +0330 2024] Using CA: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
[Sat Nov  2 14:30:34 +0330 2024] Standalone mode.
[Sat Nov  2 14:30:34 +0330 2024] Single domain='update.gerqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmgerqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm.site'
40D714598C7F0000:error:06800097:asn1 encoding routines:(unknown function):string too long:crypto/asn1/a_mbstr.c:106:maxsize=64
req: Error adding subject name attribute "/CN=update.gerqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmgerqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm.site"
[Sat Nov  2 14:30:34 +0330 2024] Error creating CSR.
[Sat Nov  2 14:30:34 +0330 2024] Please check log file for more details: /root/.acme.sh/acme.sh.log

what is that error (string too long) mean & how can i fix it?

Like you can see in the error:
"40D714598C7F0000:error:06800097:asn1 encoding routines:(unknown function):string too long:crypto/asn1/a_mbstr.c:106:maxsize=64".
According to RFC3280, the CN cannot be longer than 64 bits.
